# What does $|Du| \leq 1 $ a.e. mean for $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> What does $|Du| \leq 1 $ a.e. mean for $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

In the paper that I am reading, the authors used the notation $|Du| \leq 1 $ a.e.
I know when $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then this is the same as $\|Du\|_\infty \leq 1$, but what about when $Du$ is not necessarily a function?

For example, the distributional derivative of the jump function at $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\delta_0$, I thought we can say $\delta_0 \leq 1 $ a.e. but $\|\delta_0\|_\infty$ is not well defined since $\delta_0$ is not a function.

[Here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/267076331_Models_for_growth_of_heterogeneous_sandpiles_via_Mosco_convergence) is the link to the full paper. And this notation is even used in the abstract.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd assume it would be the $L^p$ norm of $Du$ rather than the $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the author mean the following: $u$ does beong to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and its distributional derivative can be identified with a function, which is bounded a.e. by another function.

To support my guess, note that the variable exponent Sobolev space $W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ is defined by

$$W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)=\{u\in L^{p(x)}(\Omega):\ |\nabla u|\in L^{p(x)}(\Omega)\}.$$

As you can see, they do not talk explicitly about weak derivatives or distributional derivatives, so it is safe to assume that the above definition means that the distributions $\partial u/\partial x_i$ can be identified with functions in $L^{p(x)}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The statement $|\nabla u| \in L^{p(x)}(\Omega)$ is fine with me, it means that I could identify $D^{|\alpha|} u, |\alpha| = 1$ with functions in $L^{p(x)}(\Omega)$. But I think saying $$|\nabla u| \leq 1 \text{ a.e. } \not\Rightarrow \|\nabla u \|_\infty \leq 1, $$ so there must be a reason they used this instead of $\|\nabla u \|_\infty \leq 1$. And they did use  $\|\nabla u \|_\infty \leq 1$ when assuming $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Comment: These two things are equivalent. I think that it is irrelevant if you write $|\nabla u|\le 1$ a.e. or $\|\nabla u\|_\infty\le 1$.

Comment: For example, the distributional derivative of the jump function at $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\delta_0$, I thought we can say $\delta_0 \leq 1 $ a.e. but we could not make sense of $\|\delta_0\|_\infty$ since it is not a function. I am still a little bit confused...

Comment: My guess, as I have said in the first paragraph of my answer, is that the author assumes that the distributional gradient of $u\in L^2$ can be identified with a function $\nabla u$, which is bounded a.e.. Before the identification, nothing can be said.